# How to debug why I can't access a specific website?

Tags: networking, isp

**Modem:** Huawei HG8245H Router

**Windows 7 computers**

**There are no proxies in the browsers.**

How to ensure that there is no proxy in the modem or router?

From my local network, I can't access a specific website phtek.com.br

**PING AND TRACEROUTE FROM MODEM**

I logged in the modem and tried to ping and to traceroute the website from there. First didn't work, second did.

[image: Ping and Tracert tests from within the modem]

[Full size image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/so3Qv.jpg)

**PING AND TRACEROUTE FROM ANY COMPUTER**

```
C:\>ping 142.44.144.88

Pinging 142.44.144.88 with 32 bytes of data:
Request timed out.
Request timed out.
Request timed out.
Request timed out.

Ping Statistics for 142.44.144.88:
Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 0, Lost = 4 
(100% of loss),
```

Pinging or tracerouting from any computer in the network fails.

```
1     1 ms     1 ms     7 ms  192.168.1.1
2     *        5 ms     6 ms  100.127.252.71
3    14 ms     4 ms     3 ms  200.150.94.29
4     4 ms     3 ms     4 ms  200.150.94.65
5   186 ms    24 ms    10 ms  trunk10-src1bte-src1cos.copel.net [200.150.93.97]
6    10 ms    10 ms    10 ms  200-233-138-202.xd-dynamic.ctbcnetsuper.com.br [200.233.138.202]
7    11 ms    19 ms    10 ms  et-3-0-1-0.core-a.spo511.algartelecom.com.br [170.84.33.90]
8   112 ms   121 ms   116 ms  et-0-0-1-0.monet.border-b.bct.algartelecom.com.br [168.197.23.193]
9   113 ms   113 ms   113 ms  et-2-0-2-0.border-b.mia.algartelecom.com.br [168.197.23.177]
10     *        *        *     Request timed out.
11   142 ms   142 ms   141 ms  be100.bhs-g2-nc5.qc.ca [142.44.208.69]
12     *        *        *     Request timed out.
13   144 ms   141 ms   142 ms  be50-7.bhs-3a-a9.qc.ca [198.27.73.94]
14     *        *        *     Request timed out.
15     *        *        *     Request timed out.
16     *        *        *     Request timed out.
17     *        *        *     Request timed out.
18     *        *        *     Request timed out.
19     *        *        *     Request timed out.
20     *        *        *     Request timed out.
21     *        *        *     Request timed out.
22     *        *        *     Request timed out.
23     *        *        *     Request timed out.
24     *        *        *     Request timed out.
25     *        *        *     Request timed out.
26     *        *        *     Request timed out.
27     *        *        *     Request timed out.
28     *        *        *     Request timed out.
29     *        *        *     Request timed out.
30     *        *        *     Request timed out.
```

**EXTERNAL ISP's**

My ISP is COPEL.

If I connect to any external ISP (i.e.: smartphone mobile data: TIM, VIVO etc.), from my home network, friends network, it works.

I can access the website, ping and traceroute is successful.

I only can't access the website from my office network.

Comment: I would contact the ISP first. If they say the problem isn't on their side, then I would try to troubleshoot. I can think of two different but non-exclusive hypotheses: (1) ISP block and (2) IP or range of IPs blacklisted at the destination server.

Comment: I've contacted my ISP twice. They told me they do not block sites. Also, my friend uses the same ISP and he can connect to my website. Does this imply ISP isn't blocking or still can be blocking at my office somehow?

Comment: If your friend uses the same service and can reach the website then I believe your ISP isn't blocking it. Then we go for #2.

Comment: To test the #2 hypotheses you can use a VPN or even TOR. If it works then it's being blocked or blacklisted at the destination.

Comment: right, I will give it a try...

Comment: You were right. From Tor I can get to the website, therefore my website host is blocking my access

Comment: Yes. Well, sorry about that. Try contacting them and inquire why you're being blocked. They may have blocked it due to an attack coming from that IP or from somewhere else spoofing it.

Comment: They just unblocked it ¬¬ . It's working, @Gabriela thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Website hosting was blocking my IP as GabrielaGarcia said in a comment.

After contacting my hosting, they unblocked my IP and it's working fine now.